# geom_sf() legend doesn't show a label

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-sf

It's my first time making graphs with `geom_sf` (and `ggplot2`), so I'm facing some difficulties.
I'm working with two datasets and I can't figurw out how to change the legend.
I'm using ggmap and omsdata for the baseline.

```
`bl_basemap <- get_map(location = getbb("belluno"), zoom = 9, maptype = 'toner-hybrid', source = 'stamen')
ggmap(bl_basemap) + 
  geom_sf(data = geobelluno2cdp, aes(colour = f, size=f), inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  geom_sf(data = geopnasc, fill = "red", color = "red", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "red")))+
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(4326)) +
  xlab("LONGITUDINE") +
  ylab("LATITUDINE") + 
  ggtitle("Belluno (2022)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))`
```

This code prodices the following plot

I'm trying to add the red points to the label under the one already present.

I tried adding `show.legend = "point"`, but the red points show inside the blue points.

```
`ggmap(bl_basemap) +
  geom_sf(data = geobelluno2cdp, aes(colour = f, size=f), inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  geom_sf(data = geopnasc, fill = "red", color = "red", inherit.aes = FALSE, show.legend = "point") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "red")))+
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(4326)) +
  xlab("LONGITUDINE") +
  ylab("LATITUDINE") +  
  ggtitle("Belluno (2022)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))`
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you want to show something in the legend you have to map on aesthetics, i.e. try with `geom_sf(data = geopnasc, aes(color = "red"), fill = "red", inherit.aes = FALSE)`. However, doing so will assign a color from the default color palette to the category `"red"`. If you want to assign custom colors you have to use `scale_color_manual`.

Comment: @stefan Hi! I tried your suggestion, but this error shows up "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Comment: Okay. Looks like your `f` variable is a numeric aka continuous variable. Unfortunately you can't mix continuous and categorical variables in the same scale.   One option would be to convert `f` to a factor, i.e. use e.g. `color = factor(f)`. However, whether that makes sense depends on the nature of your data, i.e. whether the values of `f` reflect categories.

Comment: @stefan If I convert f to a factor, the category "red" appears, but it appears under the "factor(f)" label. And the colors are all messed up. If I remove completely the color = f command, it works perfectly, but all my f points now are black. When I try to change the colors with `scale_color_manual`, I can change only the color for the category "red", or else the "red" label completely disappears

Comment: I can't reproduce your data: `bl_basemap <- get_map(location = getbb("belluno"), zoom = 9, maptype = 'toner-hybrid', source = 'stamen')
Error in `resp_abort()`:
! HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed.`

Comment: @Quinten I used `ggmap` and `osmdata` libraries to get the basemap